# Draggable JQuery UI - child div disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

When I drag my child div inside the parent div, it is disappearing when my mouse drags outside the boundaries. In the draggable Jquery documentation example, the child div cannot go beyond the boundaries of the parent container. Any thoughts on what my code is missing?

HTML markup:

```
<div class="containment-wrapper">
<div class="boxone" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
</div>

<div class="boxtwo" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
</div>



<div class="boxthree">
</div>

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".boxtwo").draggable({ containment: "#containment-wrapper", scroll: false });

$(".boxthree").draggable({ containment: "#containment-wrapper", scroll: false});
```

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement (I'm looking at the "I'm contained within my box" example)

- [CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/ElaineM/pen/synGB)
- [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nj5Gw/)

Comment: -1 Please show us your code or do a jsfiddle.net

Comment: Here you go, Thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/Nj5Gw/

Comment: put it in your question along with your code & your trials and i'll vote you up again

Comment: what do you want to do exactly ? you could assing an invisible parent

Comment: @pc-shooter no need to vote up while you could just remove the down vote , does really this question worth an upvote ? or you were just doing so to remove the down vote ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek I was just removing my downvote.. agree with you

Comment: @ProllyGeek Are there any other votes?

Comment: @pc-shooter yes you can just click the downvote once more , and it will be removed .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52453/discussion-between-pc-shooter-and-prollygeek)

Comment: Hi folks, thanks for your support here. Sorry to cause any trouble over this downvote/upvote issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$(".boxtwo").draggable({ containment: "#containment-wrapper", scroll: false });
$(".boxthree").draggable({ containment: "#containment-wrapper", scroll: false});
```

to this:

```
$(".boxtwo").draggable({ containment: "#containment-wrapper", scroll: false });
$(".boxthree").draggable({ containment: "parent", scroll: false});
```